# Why self.view.tag in loadview is different with others

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

when set `self.view.tag` is 10  in loadView  ,but in `viewDidload` it's **tag** is 0
why ? thanks

```
- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];
    NSLog(@"loadView %d",self.view.tag);
    [self.view setTag:10];
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
}

#pragma mark view loaded

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"ViewDidload %d",self.view.tag);
    [self.view setTag:10];
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: after one hour still no code: vote to close

Comment: <blink>- (void)loadView
{

    [super loadView];
    
    NSLog(@"loadView %d",self.view.tag);
    [self.view setTag:10];
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    
}

#pragma mark view loaded 
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"ViewDidload %d",self.view.tag);
    [self.view setTag:10];
}</blink>

Comment: I pasted your code into the question and formatted it correctly. Stack Overflow, unfortunately, doesn't support the `blink` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loadView method is not usually implemented. The system calls it in order to create your view hierarchy. At the time it's called, your views will not exist.

Why are you implementing loadView? You probably should not be.

To quote the docs:

> If you use Interface Builder to create your views and initialize the
>   view controller, you must not override this method.

What code are you putting in your loadView method?

Comment: How can explain this method- (void)loadView
{

    [super loadView];
    
    NSLog(@"loadView %d",self.view.tag);
    [self.view setTag:10];
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

   }